# Can we send 5000 request in jmeter with different ip's

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a requirement where we have to send requests with different/unique IP's and can we set 5000 unique IP's and send through JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the source IP address for the request under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

The tricky point is that the IP address (or its [alias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_aliasing))  **must exist on the operating system level** so the steps you need to take are:

1. Assign 5k IP addresses (or aliases) to your network interface(s), refer your operating system documentation for details on how this could be done
2. Put these addresses into a CSV file
3. Use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) so each thread could get the new IP address from the CSV file on each iteration
4. Use the variable from the CSV file in "Source address" field of the HTTP Request sampler
5. That should be it

More information: [Using IP Spoofing to Simulate Requests from Different IP Addresses with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter)